# Kendo.editor not decode Html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I use Kendo.EditorFor for textbox  but in view .It's show me htmls tag from editor 
this is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(OpininonModel opininonmodel)
{
    var addOpinion =
        new OpininonModel
        {
            Title=opininonmodel.Title,
            Content=Server.HtmlDecode(opininonmodel.Content),
            Id=opininonmodel.Id,
            IdUser=user,
        };
    db.Opinions.Add(addOpinion);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And i see `&lt;strong&gt;123123&lt;/strong&gt;` in my view. Should I `HtmlDecode` somewhere else or ?

I tried this in my View :

```
@(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(model => model.Content).Encode(false))
```

but this give it to me error:

`A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client`

Comment: On your opinion model add the attribute [AllowHtml] and then just use content=opinionmodel.content

Comment: not working show me this :  <strong>123123123</strong>

Comment: Did you also drop the encode(false), also where is is showing the <strong>123456</strong> ? What do you mean?

Answer (score 8):

if you use html helper that you can decode the value once you received them from your view to your controller.

its from their documentation: Here is the [link](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/editor/overview)

**Processing the editor value on the server**

The editor value will be posted as a string and mapped to a variable with the name of the widget. Note that the posted value is HTML-encoded by default, in order to circumvent the ASP.NET request validation. In order to decode the value, use the **HttpUtility.HtmlDecode** method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(string editor)
{
    string value = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(editor);

    return View();
}
```

i think this is what you looking for

Comment: still see html tag not what they do <strong>this text it's not bold</strong> after i write this :   public ActionResult Create(OpininonModel opininonmodel) Content = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(opininonmodel.Content),

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try with `encoded: false`

```
$('.editor').kendoEditor({
     encoded: false
});
```

Comment: I use Html helper something like this : Html.Kendo().EditorFor(modelItem=>modelItem.Content)

Answer (score 0):

When you use $('.editor').kendoEditor()   //without encoded:false
you should do in controller:

```
model.data = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(model.data);
ModelState.Clear();
```